# Insert base64 image to oracle using stored procedure

Tags: java, oracle, blob

Is it possible to insert string (actually base64) to database using stored procedure. I have tried various approaches. And mostly, I got errors which are "can not cast to". Sometimes my jboss server's died.

```
private class AddItemSP extends StoredProcedure {
    private static final String SPROC_NAME = "POST.addItem";

    AddItemSP (DataSource ds) {
        super(ds, SPROC_NAME);

        declareParameter(new SqlParameter("in_image", Types.VARCHAR)); // oracle: in_image IN BLOB
        declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter("out_state", Types.VARCHAR));
        declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter("out_message", Types.VARCHAR));

        compile();
    }

    public Map<String, Object> execute(String image) {
        Map<String, Object> inputs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        inputs.put("in_image", image);

        return super.execute(inputs);
    }
}
```

in this case, program will say wrong types of argument. Then I searched and read then added some code.

```
Blob blob = jdbctemplate.getDataSource().getConnection().createBlob();
blob.setBytes(1, image.getBytes());
```

And sent that blob to procedure, of course changed Types.VARCHAR to Types.BLOB. Still failed.

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Types.TEXT` and `String` because of the 255 bytes limititation? BTW always specify an encoding: `image.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)` though here (ASCII) anything would go.